# Service is not triggered or set by AlarmManager. Same codes work differently on different devices and different projects

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm sorry for asking a common question, 
but I did a lot of study and still couldn't find out the solution.

I also did a android test that I set my service to be triggered soon, but the **codes below work totally differently on my two phones**.

One of them with 7.0 android version never works, even the service was never triggered. 
Another one with 5.0 version successfully worked if I set the triggered time to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but it didn't work with any times after the current time (such as `System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000`). As well as if the notification is sent successfully, then followed by it disappears in a very short time strangely.

Here's my android test method.

```
@Test
public void setAlarm(){
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MedicationNotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() , sender);
}
```

---

Then here comes my detailed codes of service. 
MedicationNotification is just a POJO which contains the triggered time. 
The service sends the notification and set the next alarm.

```
public class MedicationNotificationService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MedicationNfService";
    public MedicationNotificationService() {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MedicationNotification notification = (MedicationNotification) intent.getSerializableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        Log.d(TAG, "Service started. notification: " + notification);
        NotificationUtils.showNotification(this, getString(R.string.itsTimeToMedicate),
                notification.getMedication().getName(), notification.getId());

        if (notification.getMedication().getEndDate().after(new Date()))  //set next notification if not expired
        {
            AlarmManagerUtils.arrangeMedicationNotification(this, notification);
            Log.d(TAG, "Medication does not expire, set the next alarm.");
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Medication expired, delete it.");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I've also made sure that I did not misspell the services' name.

```
<service
    android:name=".android.MedicationNotificationService">
</service>
```

Finally, here's the AlarmManager codes. It's as same as I did in the test method.
The id of PendingIndent's depends on MedicationNotification's id.
And set the exact time.

```
public class AlarmManagerUtils {

    public static void arrangeMedicationNotification(Context context, MedicationNotification notification){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null)
        {
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MedicationNotificationService.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION, notification);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 50000 + notification.getId(),
                    alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notification.getNotifyTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your patience, tell me if you need more information, I really spent hours solving this. It's really strange, it used to work on my another project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For setting alarm use below code

```
if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
    else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Add below line after notification `notify` method

```
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    boolean isScreenOn ;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        isScreenOn  = pm.isInteractive();
    }else {
        isScreenOn=pm.isScreenOn();
    }

    if (!isScreenOn) {

        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyLock");

        wl.acquire(10000);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyCpuLock");

        wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
    }
```

and also add this permission on manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```